# Как извлечь данные из двух таблиц в json объект

Tags: java, json, api, spring-boot, rest

Делаю rest api приложение на spring boot
я имею 2 таблицы в базе данных первой называется TblEmployees ,вторая тиблия называется TblDepartments , из этих 2 таблиц я сделал класс Employees_DTO который должен возвращать данные в Json формате. А из таблицы TblEmployees он возвращает данные а из таблицы TblDepartments он возвращает null .
вот что я сделал
заранее спасибо
`

```
public class TblEmployees {
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int emp_id;
    private String empName;
    private Boolean empActive;
    private Integer dbID;
}

public class TblDepartments {
private Integer dbID;
private String dep_name;
}

public class Employees_DTO {
    private int emp_id;
    private String empName;
    private Boolean empActive;
    private String dep_name;
}
 @Service
 public class EmployessServise {
@Autowired
private EmplployeesRepository repo;

@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

public EmployessServise() {
}

public List<Employees_DTO> getAll_Emp(){
    return repo.findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(this::convertEntityToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Employees_DTO convertEntityToDto(TblEmployees tblEmployees){
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
    Employees_DTO employees_dto=new Employees_DTO();
    employees_dto=modelMapper.map(tblEmployees,Employees_DTO.class);
    return employees_dto;
}

private TblEmployees convertEntityToDto(Employees_DTO employees_dto){
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
    TblEmployees tblEmployees=new TblEmployees();
    tblEmployees=modelMapper.map(employees_dto,TblEmployees.class);
    return tblEmployees;
}
```

Comment: Тут очень не любят вопросы состоящие из картинок. Но я всё же дам вам подсказку. Вам нужно создать класс DTO включающий атрибуты 2-ух POJO классов. И вручную создать объект DTO и присвоить атрибутам значения атрибутов POJO объектов

Comment: можете показать пример не совсем понимаю как это?

Comment: в текстовом виде, пожалуйста!..в текстовом виде...

Comment: отредактировал вопрос